# Show div on select dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show a div when the user select a option out the dropdown. It works on localhost and with codepen but when I upload the code to the server of my domain it doesn't work..

I'm struggling with this problem and have no idea why this doesn't work.

The code is very long, thats why I didn't share it here.

HTML:

```
 <select>
                <option>choose a option</option>
                <option value="test1">test 1</option>
                <option value="test2">test 2</option>
            </select>

            <div class="test1 pricebox"><strong>test1 - test2</strong> <h1>€27,50</h1></div>
            <div class="test2 pricebox"><strong>test2 - test1</strong> <h1>€27,50</h1></div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="test1"){
            $(".pricebox").not(".test1").hide();
            $(".test1").show();
        }
        else if($(this).attr("value")=="test2"){
            $(".pricebox").not(".test2").hide();
            $(".test2").show();
        }
        else{
            $(".pricebox").hide();
        }
        });
    }).change();
    });
```

The codepen (it works)
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOGvJq

Comment: F12 -> Network tab -> F5 -> Check for resource load failures.

Comment: check your javascript console log in your browser. I imagine some of your javascript isn't loading or is crashing due to an error.

Comment: it doesn't give any error

Comment: If you using Linux ,please check permissions access to folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is : you're not including the jQuery script on your website I guess.
Add this code in the  tag of your page.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
```

However check this live page I hosted this on server to show you demo.

http://shehroz.pixub.com/stack.html

Comment: I add the jQuery script source

Comment: But You can see at the source code of my webpage by pressing cntrl + U on the page.

A live demo is available at  -> http://gyazo.com/bda69899b98505b4a142aadec08d10fb

Comment: yep, I see it works but that's not the problem. it also works on the localhost and codepen. but the same code doesn't work when I upload it on the server

Comment: Show me the whole code of the file which you're uploading. May be there is an error. because I also showed you demo of a server but it's working.

Comment: http://shehroz.pixub.com/stack.html look It's corrected now :) check the source code of this.

Comment: what was the problem? what did you change?

Comment: You forgot to add your javascript code into your website.. So i just added it  .. look at the line number 378 :) 
Kindly vote up and accept it as answer if it works for you. :)

Comment: but the javascript code is also  in the script.js file which I include @Shehroz?

Comment: No you can check,code is not inside the scripts.js file.

Comment: I see it in the scripts.js file but it's working now :) thanks!